# How can I access data attribute value using useRef hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can access value of className and id by using boardRef.current.className and boardRef.current.id, but if I use boardRef.current.data-board then I get "cannot read properties of undefined". Is there any way to access data attribute using useRef hook?

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const boardRef = useRef();

  const getData = () => {
    console.log(boardRef.current.data-board);
  }
  getData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      <div ref={boardRef} className="board" id="boardOne" data-board="one"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The element does not exist in the DOM before it's rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `React#useEffect` and `Element#getAttribute`:

```
const getData = () => {
  console.log(boardRef.current.getAttribute("data-board"));
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);
```